# Unsafe or unchecked expressions in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree, unsafe, unchecked

I'm doing an assignment and I have to create an iterable collection that saves all values of a binary tree between certain tresholds. The binary tree class has a root variable, which is an object of a TreeNode class I've written. The nodes only store integer values. Here are my methods:

```
public class Tree {
    public Iterable<Integer> listing(int low, int high) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 return root.listing(lo, hi, list);
        }
}

public class TreeNode {
    public ArrayList<Integer> listing(int low, int high, ArrayList list) {
        if(this.left!=null) {
            list=this.left.listing(low, high, list);
        }

        if(this.value>=low && this.value<=high) {
            list.add(this.value);
        }

        if(this.right!=null) {
            list=this.right.listing(low, high, list);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine locally, but I have to upload it to a platform which uses Java 6, and I'm getting an error that it uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
I am getting the same message in my IDE, but it seems to imply that it's not of great importance. However, I have to fix this in some way. I tried reading up on unsafe/unchecked operations but I'm not sure I really do understand what's the problem here.
Is there any way to fix this without changing the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an error, it's a warning, but, as you noted, you should probably fix it.

The problem is that you're passing an unbound `ArrayList`, that, theoretically, can hold elements of any type, while you're only dealing with `Integer`s. So, instead, you could declare your parameter as an `ArrayList` of `Integer`s:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> listing(int low, int high, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
```

Edit:
By the way, there's no need to have an **Array**List in the method's declaration. Since the only thing you care about here is `List` interface and not it's implementation, you can clear up the declaration a bit:

```
public List<Integer> listing(int low, int high, List<Integer> list) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> listing(
        int low, int high, ArrayList list) {
//                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

It's unsafe because this lets me pass any kind of `ArrayList`:

```
root.listing(lo, hi, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc")));
```

Use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList`.